# How to identify functions and modularize code in python?

Tags: python, function, modularity

The below program is written to perform different operations in a bank.
How to identify functions that can be written and modularize the code ?

Also I need grouping the appropriate codes into the identified functions.

```
account_list=[1001,1002,1003,1004,1005]
balance_list=[2500,10000,7000,1500,500]
amount=1000
account_number=1003
transaction_type="Withdraw"

flag=None
if(transaction_type=="Withdraw"):
    for index in range(0,len(account_list)):
        if(account_list[index]==account_number):
            flag=True
            value=index
    if(flag==True):
        balance=balance_list[value]
        new_balance=balance-amount
        if(new_balance >= 500):
            balance_list[value]=new_balance
            print("Transaction completed successfully")
            print("Balance Amount :", new_balance)
        else:
            print("Insufficient Balance")
    else:
        print("Invalid Account number")

elif(transaction_type=="Deposit"):
    for index in range(0,len(account_list)):
        if(account_list[index]==account_number):
            flag=True
            value=index
    if(flag==True):
        balance=balance_list[value]
        new_balance=balance+amount
        balance_list[value]=new_balance
        print("Transaction completed successfully")
        print("Balance Amount :", new_balance)
    else:
        print("Invalid Account number")
elif(transaction_type=="Balance Enquiry"):
    for index in range(0,len(account_list)):
        if(account_list[index]==account_number):
            flag=True
            value=index
    if(flag==True):
        balance=balance_list[value]
        print(balance)
    else:
        print("Invalid Account number")
else:
    print("Invalid Transaction Type")
```

Also explanations will help me learn it.

Comment: Hi @Arijeet, welcome to Stackoverflow. You should ask this type of question on [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) website.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by __modularizing__ your code?

Comment: @InfectedDrake It's about dividing your code into multiple functions.

Comment: @Arijeet, functions are meant to be used only to avoid code reuse. So if in your code, you're using a snippet more than once, then of course you should host the snippet as a function and call it wherever you're requiring it.

Answer (score 0):

while doing programming the base criteria for function is the functionality of your program. For your example instead of `if` conditions and the respective code you can make function for each operation e.g. withdraw:

```
def withdraw(amount, account_list, account_number, balance_list):
    '''
    function description
    '''
    for index in range(0,len(account_list)):
        if(account_list[index]==account_number):
            flag=True
            value=index
    if(flag==True):
        balance=balance_list[value]
        new_balance=balance-amount
        if(new_balance >= 500):
            balance_list[value]=new_balance
            print("Transaction completed successfully")
            print("Balance Amount :", new_balance)
        else:
            print("Insufficient Balance")
    else:
        print("Invalid Account number")
```